# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

i'm trying to return a list to show all of my content which is in a table which their id is equal to _id (in first If statement otherwise return all ) but i get this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List (Project1.Models.EF_Model.Phone_book) to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Project1.Models.EF_Model.Phone_BookEntities1)

and here's my code

```
public List<Models.EF_Model.Phone_BookEntities1> Select(int? _id)
{
       var Ref_Phone = new Models.EF_Model.Phone_BookEntities1();
        if (_id.HasValue)
        {
            return Ref_Phone.Phone_book.Where(p => p.Id == _id); //here error shows up
        }
        else
        {
            Ref_Phone.Phone_book.ToList();
        }
}
```

i tried to add this *.ToList()* it didn't work i don't know what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a list of `Phone_book` instead of `Models.EF_Model.Phone_BookEntities1` which is your context type:

```
public List<Models.EF_Model.Phone_book> Select(int? _id)
{
    var Ref_Phone = new Models.EF_Model.Phone_BookEntities1();
    return id.HasValue? Ref_Phone.Phone_book.Where(p => p.Id == _id).ToList():Ref_Phone.Phone_book.ToList();

}
```

Comment: thank you so much,is it posible to write this in normal form of IF instead of inline version?or it's something that has to get done in in line form?

Comment: Of course, you can do it using an `if` clause. I did it that way to do it shorter

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `(` on `(Ref_Phone` and put `.ToList()` on the end of there linq expression.

Comment: That's not very helpful -- explain precisely why it's not working (compiler errors, unexpected results, etc) or we can't help.